# MongoDB rename database field within array

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, rename

I need to rename `indentifier` in this:

```
{ "general" : 
  { "files" : 
    { "file" : 
      [  
        {  "version" : 
          {  "software_program" : "MonkeyPlus",      
             "indentifier" : "6.0.0" 
          } 
        } 
      ] 
    } 
  } 
}
```

I've tried

```
db.nrel.component.update(
  {},
  { $rename: {
    "general.files.file.$.version.indentifier" : "general.files.file.$.version.identifier"
  } },
  false, true
)
```

but it returns: `$rename source may not be dynamic array`.

Comment: `$rename` does not expand arrays, [doc](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24rename)

Comment: @Alexander Azarov, any ideas on fixing this? i've heard of people copying to fields in which $rename can go...

Comment: Personally I am writing scripts walking through the collection and doing migrations

Comment: If you are looking to do this with database commands: [How to rename a field inside an array with database commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66262183/7910454)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#behavior) there is no way to directly rename fields within arrays with a single command. Your only option is to iterate over your collection documents, read them and update each with `$unset` old/`$set` new operations.

Comment: Stuck with MongoDB... things like this make me sad :(

Comment: I don't disagree. This is relatively low hanging fruit I'd imagine.

Comment: This answer is outdated, see Sudhesh's answer which IMO is the best

Answer (score 56):

For what it's worth, while it sounds awful to have to do, the solution is actually pretty easy. This of course depends on how many records you have. But here's my example:

```
db.Setting.find({ 'Value.Tiers.0.AssetsUnderManagement': { $exists: 1 } }).snapshot().forEach(function(item)
{    
    for(i = 0; i != item.Value.Tiers.length; ++i)
    {
        item.Value.Tiers[i].Aum = item.Value.Tiers[i].AssetsUnderManagement;
        delete item.Value.Tiers[i].AssetsUnderManagement;
    }
    
    db.Setting.update({_id: item._id}, item);
});
```

I iterate over my collection where the array is found and the "wrong" name is found. I then iterate over the sub collection, set the new value, delete the old, and update the whole document. It was relatively painless. Granted I only have a few tens of thousands of rows to search through, of which only a few dozen meet the criteria.

Still, I hope this answer helps someone!

Edit: Added `snapshot()` to the query. See why in the comments.

> You must apply `snapshot()` to the cursor before retrieving any documents from the database.
> You can only use `snapshot()` with unsharded collections.

**From MongoDB 3.4, `snapshot()` function was removed. So if using Mongo 3.4+ ,the example above should remove `snapshot()` function.**

Comment: Imho this should be the accepted answer. I performed this approach on several collections with up to twelve million documents each and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Absolutely. This works great. A pity MongoDB is not able yet to include this behaviour natively.

Comment: It's better to use snapshot():
`db.Setting.find({ 'Value.Tiers.0.AssetsUnderManagement': { $exists: 1 } }).snapshot().forEach(...)`
Otherwise you can end up in an infinite loop.
See also https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.snapshot/

Comment: New one to me. Thanks for the details, @PatrycjaK! Updating my answer.

Comment: @Andrew Samuelsen I think this should be the selected answer - a script to work around the "by design" problem

Comment: @PatrycjaK: [`snapshot` is deprecated](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#snapshot) as of MongoDB 4.0.

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar problem. In my situation I found the following was much easier:

1. I exported the collection to json:

```
mongoexport --db mydb --collection modules --out modules.json
```

2. I did a find and replace on the json using my favoured text editing utility.
3. I reimported the edited file, dropping the old collection along the way:

```
mongoimport --db mydb --collection modules --drop --file modules.json
```

Comment: I'm kinda skeptical how well this approach works on a large dataset. Say my db is 5gb, this process sounds slow. Or perhaps I'm not using the right text editing tools =-}

Comment: Also be cautious of live databases. If records get added/modified in the time it takes to do these steps, changes will be lost.

Comment: This is okay if you have something that only runs on your laptop but isn't a viable solution if you're working in a production environment.

Answer (score 20):

Starting `Mongo 4.2`, [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update of a field based on its own value:

```
// { general: { files: { file: [
//   { version: { software_program: "MonkeyPlus", indentifier: "6.0.0" } }
// ] } } }
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{ $set: { "general.files.file": {
       $map: {
         input: "$general.files.file",
         as: "file",
         in: {
           version: {
             software_program: "$$file.version.software_program",
             identifier: "$$file.version.indentifier" // fixing the typo here
           }
         }
       }
  }}}]
)
// { general: { files: { file: [
//   { version: { software_program: "MonkeyPlus", identifier: "6.0.0" } }
// ] } } }
```

---

Literally, this `update`s documents by (re)`$set`ting the `"general.files.file"` array by `$map`ping its `"file"` elements `in` a `"version"` object containing the same `"software_program"` field and the renamed `"identifier"` field which contains what used to be the value of `"indentifier"`.

---

A couple additional details:

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update (in this case all documents).
- The second part `[{ $set: { "general.files.file": { ... }}}]` is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline):

  - [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator which in this case replaces the value of the `"general.files.file"` array.
  - Using a [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) operation, we replace all elements from the `"general.files.file"` array by basically the same elements, but with an `"identifier"` field rather than `"indentifier"`:
  - `input` is the array to map.
  - `as` is the variable name given to looped elements
  - `in` is the actual transformation applied on elements. In this case, it replaces elements by a `"version"` object composed by a `"software_program"` and a `"identifier"` fields. These fields are populated by extracting their previous values using the `$$file.xxxx` notation (where `file` is the name given to elements from the `as` part).

Comment: You were keep `software_program` manually.
But what if version field has alot of children fields, and may be difference fields in each documents?

Comment: To answer @HaidangNguyen's question, and in general a good practice - use `$mergeObjects` in `$map`'s `in` :) In the case of the example above: `in: { $mergeObjects: ['$$file', / * changes here */] }`.

Answer (score 11):

I had to face the issue with the same schema. So this query will helpful for someone who wants to rename the field in an embedded array.

```
db.getCollection("sampledocument").updateMany({}, [
  {
    $set: {
      "general.files.file": {
        $map: {
          input: "$general.files.file",
          in: {
            version: {
              $mergeObjects: [
                "$$this.version",
                { identifer: "$$this.version.indentifier" },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  { $unset: "general.files.file.version.indentifier" },
]);
```

[Another Solution](https://codetrojan.com/mongodb/how-to-rename-an-array-field-in-mongodb/)

Answer (score 6):

I also would like rename a property in array: and I used thaht

```
db.getCollection('YourCollectionName').find({}).snapshot().forEach(function(a){
    a.Array1.forEach(function(b){
        b.Array2.forEach(function(c){
            c.NewPropertyName = c.OldPropertyName;
            delete c["OldPropertyName"];                   
        });
    });
    db.getCollection('YourCollectionName').save(a)  
});
```

Comment: [`snapshot` is deprecated](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Cursor.html#snapshot) as of MongoDB 4.0.

Comment: Also you could add         if(b.hasOwnProperty("xxx"))
for verifying that property or array exists.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and shortest solution using aggregate (Mongo 4.0+).

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "myArray.newField": {$arrayElemAt: ["$myArray.oldField", 0] }
    }
  },
  {$project: { "myArray.oldField": false}},
  {$out: {db: "myDb", coll: "myCollection"}}
])
```

The problem using forEach loop as mention above is the very bad performance when the collection is huge.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal would be this one:

```
db.nrel.component.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$general.files.file" },
   {
      $set: {
         "general.files.file.version.identifier": {
            $ifNull: ["$general.files.file.version.indentifier", "$general.files.file.version.identifier"]
         }
      }
   },
   { $unset: "general.files.file.version.indentifier" },
   { $set: { "general.files.file": ["$general.files.file"] } },
   { $out: "nrel.component" } // carefully - it replaces entire collection.
])
```

However, this works only when array `general.files.file` has a single document only. Most likely this will not always be the case, then you can use this one:

```
db.nrel.componen.aggregate([
   { $unwind: "$general.files.file" },
   {
      $set: {
         "general.files.file.version.identifier": {
            $ifNull: ["$general.files.file.version.indentifier", "$general.files.file.version.identifier"]
         }
      }
   },
   { $unset: "general.files.file.version.indentifier" },
   { $group: { _id: "$_id", general_new: { $addToSet: "$general.files.file" } } },
   { $set: { "general.files.file": "$general_new" } },
   { $unset: "general_new" },
   { $out: "nrel.component" } // carefully - it replaces entire collection.
])
```

Comment: too complicated for such a simple task