# Renaming a field in an embedded Document in an Array in MongoDB not working

Tags: arrays, mongodb, field, rename

**Step One**

```
> db.myCollection.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("2358523892345"), "field1" : "value 1", "field2" : [ { "subfield1" : "value 2" }, { "Subfield2" : "value 3" } ], "field3" : "value 4" }
```

I am wanting to rename the field `Subfield2` to `subfield2`.  I tried:

**Step Two**

```
> db.myCollection.update ( { "field3": "value 4" }, {$rename: {"Subfield2": "subfield2" } } )
```

And then ran find() again and get the same results as in 'Step One' ie the field is not renamed.

Using MongoDB terminology, I think what I am trying to do is 'rename a field in an embedded document in an array'.

**References**

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB rename database field within array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to not be possible to rename a field within an array from the command line as answered in this question:

[MongoDB rename database field within array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array)

> As mentioned in the documentation there is no way to rename fields
>   within arrays. Your only option is to iterate over your collection
>   documents, read them and update each with $unset old/$set new
>   operations.

It is possible to change these values via RockMongo however as suggested by user Liad Livnat.

For my particular instance, whist there I also removed the array and changed the structure to:

```
{
  "field1": "value 1",
  "field2": {"subfield1": "value 2", "subfield2": "value 3"},
  "field3": "value 4"
}
```

Querying this object was then possible with:

```
db.myCollection.find( {"field2.subfield2":"value 3"} );
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to update it manually i suggest you will install rockmongo, rockmongo is a great tool working with mongo databases, just extract it on your server and connect to your database.
there you will find very easy update to mongo database, tables and records.

[rock mongo](http://rockmongo.com/downloads)