# How to rename keys of items in an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am very new to MongoDB and I need to do a somewhat complex Update operation on my collection.

I have this kind of collection:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "extension": [
      {
        "keyName": "Name",
        "value": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "keyAge": "Age",
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "extension": [
      {
        "keyName": "Name",
        "value": "Sam"
      },
      {
        "key": "Name",
        "value": "Sam"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "extension": [
      {
        "keyName": "Age",
        "value": 25
      },
      {
        "key": "Age",
        "value": 25
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 4
  }
]
```

I would like to update any items in the `extension` array of all documents

so that when an item is found with a `key` property, to rename it `keyAge`.

Here is the expected result:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "extension": [
      {
        "keyName": "Name",
        "value": "Bob"
      },
      {
        "keyAge": "Age",
        "value": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "extension": [
      {
        "keyName": "Name",
        "value": "Sam"
      },
      {
        "keyAge": "Name",
        "value": "Sam"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "extension": [
      {
        "keyName": "Age",
        "value": 25
      },
      {
        "keyAge": "Age",
        "value": 25
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 4
  }
]
```

I tried to use `$rename` in a similar way to this question:
[MongoDB rename database field within array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array)
but I get the same error `$rename source may not be dynamic array`

I think this solution might also apply to me, I tried using it but it's not updating anything on my side, so I guess I cannot understand how to apply that answer to me...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193743/215553

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I tried to use `$rename` in a similar way to this question: MongoDB rename database field within array but I get the same error `$rename source may not be dynamic array`*

There is a note in [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#behavior):

> `$rename` does not work if these fields are in array elements.

You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- check condition id `key` field is exists
- `$map` to iterate loop of `extension` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of array that is converted from `extension` object to array in key-value format
- `$cond` check condition if `k` is `key` then return `keyAge` otherwise return current
- `$arrayToObject` back to convert key-value array return from above map to object original format

```
db.collection.update(
  { "extension.key": { $exists: true } },
  [{
    $set: {
      extension: {
        $map: {
          input: "$extension",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$$this" },
                in: {
                  k: {
                    $cond: [
                      { $eq: ["$$this.k", "key"] }, // check "key" field name
                      "keyAge", // update new name "keyAge"
                      "$$this.k"
                    ]
                  },
                  v: "$$this.v"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wCxEgsJz5xW)

Comment: that is weird, it's working in the playground but not when I execute the query in MongoDBCompass on my data...`{ acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: null,
  matchedCount: 0,
  modifiedCount: 0,
  upsertedCount: 0 }`

Comment: can you show screenshot how you are executing this query in monbodb compass. i would suggest do this kind of operation in mongo shell, because mongodb compass is still in beta version.

Comment: Like that: https://i.imgur.com/C8OmiYn.png I will try to understand...I think your answer is the right one :) Thanks!

Comment: ahh first command `use <your database name>` second use your collection name `db.<your collection name>.update(..`

Answer (score 0):

Question : How to Rename or add new key for existing array object key?

**Answer : Inside projection of mongodb query we have map property which will resolve this.**

Solution Example :

```
{
  parents: {
    $map: {
      input: "$parents",
      as: "parent",
      in: {
        caaUserId: "$$parent._id",
        email: "$$parent.email",
        countryCode: "$$parent.countryCode",
        mobile: "$$parent.mobile",
        reportType : "single"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this example if we want to rename `$parent._id` as `caaUserId` in parents array for each Element.
Then we can use map and define caaUserId like `$$parent._id`. This whole code will work in mongoose projection of Query.

It should return following :

```
{
    "parents" : [
        {
            "caaUserId" : "62d17fa164057000149e283f", 
            "email" : "john.doe@hotmail.com", 
            "countryCode" : 91,
            "mobile": 9876543210,
            "reportType":"single",
        },
        {
            "caaUserId" : "6195d50f15ae2b001293c486", 
            "email" : "akka.ash@hotmail.com", 
            "countryCode" : 91,
            "mobile": 9876543211,
            "reportType":"multi",
        },
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is something that works in your case. Might not be the most readable though.

```
import json

data = json.loads(strdata)
for entry in data:
    if 'extension' in entry:
        for x in entry['extension']:
            for k, v in x.items():
                if k == 'key':
                    x['keyAge'] = x.pop(k)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Can this be run from MongoDB Compass..? I am used to doing db.collection.updateMany...etc.

Comment: Also I think I need to use Mongo Aggregation pipelines for performance...I have many hundreds of thousands of documents to update this way