# update deeply nested document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have this collection

```
> db.styles.find({"_id":"EP65"}).pretty();
{
    "__v" : 6,
    "_id" : "EP65",
    "colours" : {
        "GRYM" : [
            {
                "on_sale" : false,
                "size_code_id" : "XS",
                "sku" : "EP65-GRYM0"
            },
            {
                "on_sale" : false,
                "size_code_id" : "2XL",
                "sku" : "EP65-GRYM5"
            }
        ],
        "BLUT" : [
            {
                "on_sale" : false,
                "size_code_id" : "XS",
                "sku" : "EP65-BLUT0"
            },
            {
                "on_sale" : false,
                "size_code_id" : "X",
                "sku" : "EP65-BLUT1"

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I would like to rename the "on_sale" to "visible", I have about 200 styles each of which has one or many colours.

So basically I want to loop through all the styles collection and for each colour.key rename the "on_sale" to "visible"

any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB rename database field within array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation there is no way to rename fields within arrays. Your only option is to iterate over your collection documents, read them and update each with $unset old/$set new operations.