# Query and filter key names instead of values in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I want to find all key names from a collection that partially match a certain string.

The closest I got was to check if a certain key exists, but that's an exact match:

```
db.collection.find({ "fkClientID": { $exists:1 }})
```

I'd like to get all keys that start with `fk` instead.

Comment: did you mean mongoliandb or monsilverdb or what?

Comment: Hahaha. No, MongoDb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the latest MongoDB 3.4.4 then you can use `$objectToArray` in an aggregate statement with [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) as the **the most** blazing fast way this can possibly be done with native operators. Not that scanning the collection is "fast". but as fast as you get for this:

```js
db[collname].aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$gt": [
          { "$size": { "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "as": "doc",
            "cond": {
              "$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$$doc.k", 0, 2 ] }, "fk" ]
            }
          }}},
          0
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }}
 ])
```

The presently undocumented `$objectToArray` translates an "object" into "key" and "value" form in an array. So this:

```js
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }
```

Becomes this:

```js
[{ "k": "a", "v": 1 }, { "k": "b", "v": 2 }]
```

Used with `$$ROOT` which is a special variable referring to the current document "object", we translate to an array so the values of `"k"` can be inspected.

Then it's just a matter of applying `$filter` and using `$substr` to get the preceding characters of the "key" string.

---

For the record, this would be the MongoDB 3.4.4 optimal way of obtaining an unique list of the matching keys:

```js
db[collname].aggregate([
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$gt": [
          { "$size": { "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
            "as": "doc",
            "cond": {
              "$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$$doc.k", 0, 2 ] }, "fk" ]
            }
          }}},
          0
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    }
  }},
  { "$project": { 
    "j": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
         "as": "doc",
         "cond": {
           "$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$$doc.k", 0, 2 ] }, "fk" ]
         }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$j" },
  { "$group": { "_id": "$j.k" }}
 ])
```

That's the safe provision, which is considering that the key may not be present in all documents and that there could possibly be multiple keys in the document.

If you are absolutely certain that you "always" have the key present in the document and that there will only be one, then you can shorten to just `$group`:

```js
db[colname].aggregate([
  { "$group": { 
    "_id": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": { "$filter": {
            "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },
             "as": "doc",
             "cond": {
               "$eq": [ { "$substr": [ "$$doc.k", 0, 2 ] }, "fk" ]
             }
          }},
          "as": "el",
          "in": "$$el.k"
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
 ])
```

---

The most efficient way in earlier versions would be using the [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) syntax that allows a JavaScript expression to evaluate. Not that anything that evaluates JavaScript is the "most" efficient thing you can do, but analyzing "keys" as opposed to "data" is not optimal for any data store:

```js
db[collname].find(function() { return Object.keys(this).some( k => /^fk/.test(k) ) })
```

The inline `function` there is just shell shorthand and this could also be written as:

```js
db[collname].find({ "$where": "return Object.keys(this).some( k => /^fk/.test(k) )" })
```

The only requirement for [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) is that the expression returns a `true` value for any document you want to return, so the documents return unaltered.

Comment: It says operator not found for $objectToArray when I tried it.

Comment: db[collname].find({ "$where": "return Object.keys(this).some( k => /^fk/.test(k) )" })   Works however

Comment: Follow up on that, how do project just the found "fk" key that I found instead of the entire document?

Comment: @mskw As noted in the answer, you need the very latest [MongoDB 3.4.4 release](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4/) where the  `$obectjToArray` operator was added. So new there is not a manual page yet. What are you looking for actually? Returning all the documents that match but "only" the fields that match the expression?

Comment: I'm trying to create a list of all keys that contain fk.  (foreign keys), then next step is to replace fk with pk (primary key) and find the doc that contain the pk.  Then replace it with an OBJectID.  Basically, I had a MDB MSAccess and need to convert it to mongo db.    Is a pain to do it by hand, so I'm devising a script, and this is part one of that script.

Comment: @mskw If all you **need** is to extract the unique list of key names as starting with the characters, and you are **not** using MongoDB 3.4.4 then the best bet is `.mapReduce()`. The `$where` clause cannot alter document structure, nor can you "project" based on the pattern of a key name. As for replacing the values, then you will need an individual update statement for each possible key name. There are optimal ways to do that, but that's another question.

Comment: @mskw Well I knew that already since I did test the code of course. If you are simply after just the unique list of matching properties, then I also added listings to do just that. As noted before, it is preferable in performance terms ( and possibly in terms of the returned cursor if there are a lot of results ) to run the aggregate statement as opposed to executing JavaScript on the server, as `$where` or `.mapReduce()` does.

Comment: Awesome answer, but I actually don't understand what the new query you added is supposed to be doing.

Comment: There are many operators I don't know about that you've used, so I will need time to understand them.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/):

**To get just the field names at root level:**

```
db.collection.mapReduce(function () {
    Object.keys(this).map(function(key) {
        if (key.match(/^fk/)) emit(key, null);

        // OR: key.indexOf("fk") === 0
    });
}, function(/* key, values */) {
    // No need for params or to return anything in the 
    // reduce, just pass an empty function.
}, { out: { inline: 1 }});
```

This will output something like this:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "_id": "fkKey1",
        "value": null
    }, {
        "_id": "fkKey2",
        "value": null
    }, {
        "_id": "fkKey3",
        "value": null
    }],
    "timeMillis": W,
    "counts": {
        "input": X,
        "emit": Y,
        "reduce": Z,
        "output": 3
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**To get field names and any or all (whole doc) its values:**

```
db.test.mapReduce(function () {
    var obj = this;

    Object.keys(this).map(function(key) {
        // With `obj[key]` you will get the value of the field as well.
        // You can change `obj[key]` for:
        //  - `obj` to return the whole document.
        //  - `obj._id` (or any other field) to return its value.

        if (key.match(/^fk/)) emit(key, obj[key]);
    });
}, function(key, values) {
    // We can't return values or an array directly yet:

    return { values: values };
}, { out: { inline: 1 }});
```

This will output something like this:

```
{
    "results": [{
        "_id": "fkKey1",
        "value": {
            "values": [1, 4, 6]
        }
    }, {
        "_id": "fkKey2",
        "value": {
            "values": ["foo", "bar"]
        }
    }],
    "timeMillis": W,
    "counts": {
        "input": X,
        "emit": Y,
        "reduce": Z,
        "output": 2
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

**To get field names in subdocuments (without path):**

To do that you will have to use [`store JavaScript functions on the Server`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/):

```
db.system.js.save({ _id: "hasChildren", value: function(obj) {
    return typeof obj === "object";
}});

db.system.js.save({ _id: "getFields", value: function(doc) {
    Object.keys(doc).map(function(key) {
        if (key.match(/^fk/)) emit(key, null);

        if (hasChildren(doc[key])) getFields(doc[key])
    });
}});
```

And change your map to:

```
function () {
    getFields(this);
}
```

Now run `db.loadServerScripts()` to load them.

**To get field names in subdocuments (with path):**

The previous version will just return field names, not the whole path to get them, which you will need if what you want to do is rename those keys. To get the path:

```
db.system.js.save({ _id: "getFields", value: function(doc, prefix) {
    Object.keys(doc).map(function(key) {
        if (key.match(/^fk/)) emit(prefix + key, null);

        if (hasChildren(doc[key]))
            getFields(doc[key], prefix + key + '.')
    });
}});
```

And change your map to:

```
function () {
    getFields(this, '');
}
```

**To exclude overlapping path matches:**

Note that if you have a field `fkfoo.fkbar`, it will return `fkfoo` and `fkfoo.fkbar`. If you don't want overlapping path matches, then:

```
db.system.js.save({ _id: "getFields", value: function(doc, prefix) {
    Object.keys(doc).map(function(key) {
        if (hasChildren(doc[key]))
            getFields(doc[key], prefix + key + '.')
        else if (key.match(/^fk/)) emit(prefix + key, null);
    });
}});
```

**Going back to your question, renaming those fields:**

With this last option, you get all the paths that include keys that start with `fk`, so you can use [`$rename`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) for that.

However, `$rename` doesn't work for those that contain arrays, so for those you could use [`forEach`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) to do the update. See [MongoDB rename database field within array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array#answer-26050901)

**Performance note:**

MapReduce is not particularly fast thought, so you may want to specify `{ out: "fk_fields"}` to output the results into a new collection called `fk_fields` and query those results later, but that will depend on your use case.

**Possible optimisations for specific cases (consistent schema):**

Also, note that if you know that the schema of your documents is always the same, then you just need to check one of them to get its fields, so you can do that adding `limit: 1` to the options object or just retrieving one document with [`findOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) and reading its fields in the application level.

Comment: The failing here is the return would be one document per matched key name rather than identifying the documents that have a key that matches. Also I think you missed the intent of the `.limit(0)` in the question. Since `.limit(0)` actually does not limit results at all.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, I know. I have updated my answer to be able to retrieve just the field names, both field name and all values or field name and all full documents. The `.limit(1)` was just a suggestion in case the schema is consistent across all the documents.

Comment: Actually If you read the OP's comments on my own answer here, it turns out that a single reduced list of the field names is all they are actually after.