# Rename array document in Mongo 3.4

Tags: mongodb

Given the following document, I want to rename "Doc" to "doc". I thought maybe I could use $rename within a forEach but no such luck.

```
db.getCollection('Docs').find({}).forEach(
function(doc){        
    doc.history.forEach(function(d2){                        
        var id = d2._id
       db.collection.update(d2, {$rename:{"Doc": "doc"}});
       print(d2);
    })                
}
)


{
"_id": "ObjectId(\"5b85c223e959480ea8b2c6d2",
"history"[{
        "Doc": {},
        "Doc": {},
        "Doc": {}
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB rename database field within array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array)

Comment: This is indeed a duplicate, and there are answers that would work for you in your case (specifically see Eli Gassert's answer midway down the page.

Comment: I had tried that example and couldn't get it to work. I'm using Robo 3T. The only message I get back is Script executed successfully, but there are no results to show. 
Maybe I'm not understanding it correctly. The loop is going through item.Value.Tiers. Is Value.Tiers an internal object?

Comment: This worked for me:
db.Docs.find({ 'history': { $exists: 1 } }).snapshot().forEach(function(item)
{      
    item.history.forEach(function(item2){        
        item2.doc = item2.Doc;
        delete item2["Doc"];
        print(item2);
    })
    
    db.Docs.save(item);
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
db.Docs.find({ 'history': { $exists: 1 } }).snapshot().forEach(function(item)
{      
    item.history.forEach(function(item2){        
        item2.doc = item2.Doc;
        delete item2["Doc"];
        print(item2);
    })

    db.Docs.save(item);
});
```