# How to change attribute name of the embed type?

Tags: mongodb

How I can change the name of the embed type by query $rename?

`{ list_name: [{ name_1: String }] } => { list_name: [{ name_2: String }] }`

I tried `db.getCollection('test').updateMany({}, { $rename: { 'list_name.name_1': 'name_2' }})`

But it's throwing an error: `WriteError: cannot use the part (list_name of list_name.name_1) to traverse the element ({list_name: [ { name_1: "test" } ]})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $rename does not work if these fields are in array elements

[Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/#behavior)

To achieve, you need `$unset` and `$set` document by document. You can use `bulkwrite` also.

`list_name` is an array. Hence `$rename` didn't work.

When I search, I get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array). You can refer the second answer if you have less number of docs.

Else, you need to use either `bulk write` or `mongo dump options`.