# Mongodb: Get value from $[<identifier>] in update

Tags: mongodb

I want to rename a field inside a object itself inside a nested array.
As example, I want to rename the all tags `m2` to `m6` in this document:

```
{
"_id": 1,
"tagsGroup": [
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "tags": {
      "m1": 1,
      "m2": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "tags": {
      "m3": 1,
      "m2": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1234",
    "tags": {
      "m4": 2,
      "m5": 2
    }
  },
  
]
}
```

This is my current state of work:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  "$set": {"tagsGroup.$[tGp].tags.m6": "$tagsGroup.$[tGp].tags.m2"},
  "$unset": {"tagsGroup.$[tGp].tags.m2": ""}
},
{
  arrayFilters: [{"tGp.tags.m2": {$exists: 1}}],
  multi: true}
)
```

Unfortunately, the `$tagsGroup.$[tGp].tags.m6` is not interpreted.
Do you guys, have a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably similar to this question [MongoDB rename database field within array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array),

There is no straight way to rename fields within arrays with a single command. You can try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB v4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `tagsGroup` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of `tags` object after converting to array using `$objectToArray`, it will return in k and v format
- `$replaceOne` will replace specific string on find field, this is starting from MongoDB v4.4
- `$arrayToObject` convert `tags` array returned by second `$map` back to object format
- `$mergeObjects` to merge current object with updated `tags` object

```
db.collection.update(
  { "tagsGroup.tags.m2": { $exists: true } },
  [{
    $set: {
      tagsGroup: {
        $map: {
          input: "$tagsGroup",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                tags: {
                  $arrayToObject: {
                    $map: {
                      input: { $objectToArray: "$$this.tags" },
                      in: {
                        k: {
                          $replaceOne: {
                            input: "$$this.k",
                            find: "m2",
                            replacement: "m6"
                          }
                        },
                        v: "$$this.v"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gjt3U_1PZ7n)

Comment: Wow.... Thanks you! Too bad there is no easier way because I have to do this with the Spring Data API lol