# How to rename a field inside an array with database commands?

Tags: mongodb

Disclaimer: Even though similar, not the same as [MongoDB rename database field within array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122966/mongodb-rename-database-field-within-array).

I want to change the key of a field from `name` to `title` with [database commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) and NOT the [shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/). I found out that using [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/index.html) is not possible inside an array. So I turned to [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) and [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) and created this:

```
db.runCommand({
    update: 'apps',
    updates: [
        {
            q: {versions: {$elemMatch: {title: {$exists: false}}}},
            u: {
                $set: {'versions.$.title': '$name'}
            },
            multi: true
        },
        {
            q: {versions: {$elemMatch: {name: {$exists: true}}}},
            u: {
                $unset: {'versions.$.name': ''}
            },
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
```

This works somewhat. It does all I want but it changes every title/name to the string "$name" instead of the value of the field `name`.

I also tried this:

```
db.runCommand({
    update: 'apps',
    updates: [
        {
            q: {versions: {$elemMatch: {title: {$exists: false}}}},
            u: {
                $set: {
                    versions: {
                        $map: {
                            input: "versions",
                            as: 'each',
                            in: {
                                "title": "$$each.name"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            multi: true
        },
        {
            q: {versions: {$elemMatch: {name: {$exists: true}}}},
            u: {
                $unset: {'versions.$.name': ''}
            },
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
```

But that just results in `[The dollar ($) prefixed field '$map' in 'versions.$map' is not valid for storage.]`. How would I go about renaming a field inside an array?

Below is a minified version of my apps collection for reference. I literally only want to change every key called `name` into `title`.

```
[{
  identifier: "x",
  versions: [
    {
      name: "test_name"
      version: "x.x.x"
    },
    {
      name: "test_name"
      version: "x.x.x"
    },
  ]
},
{
  identifier: "y",
  versions: [
    {
      name: "test_name2"
      version: "x.x.x"
    },
    {
      name: "test_name2"
      version: "x.x.x"
    },
  ]
}, ... ]
```

Comment: Try this `$map`'s `in: { version: "$$each.version" , title: "$$each.name" }` for the `$set` _and_ remove the `$unset` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *But that just results in `The dollar ($) prefixed field '$map' in 'versions.$map' is not valid for storage.`.*

- The error says `$map`'s `input` accepts reference field using `$` sign *`$version`*,
- enclose the `u` object in array bracket for [update with an aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline)
- just put both field `title` and `version` in `$map`
- `$unset` is not required because `$map` will replace old data with new fields in `in`

```
db.runCommand({
    update: 'apps',
    updates: [
        {
            q: { "versions.name": { $exists: true } },
            u: [{
                $set: {
                    versions: {
                        $map: {
                            input: "$versions",
                            in: {
                                "title": "$$this.name",
                                "version": "$$this.version"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2ETZsuIYqGA)

---

Second way, For more dynamic approach

- `$mergeObjects` inside `$map`, to prevent manual list of key-values pair
- `$unset` stage to remove `name` field from `version` array

```
db.runCommand({
    update: 'apps',
    updates: [
        {
            q: { "versions.name": { $exists: true } },
            u: [
              {
                $set: {
                    versions: {
                        $map: {
                            input: "$versions",
                            in: {
                                $mergeObjects: [
                                    "$$this",
                                    { "title": "$$this.name" }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              },
              { $unset: "versions.name" }
            ],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5W_OpQaBRAo)

Comment: Is there another way of iterating over an array if `$map` is not available?

Comment: can you explain for what reason $map is not available? is there any version issue?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, we are bound to using Azure CosmosDB for MongoDB (3.6 version) and it doesn't support `$map` as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36)

Comment: $map is the second thing, first it will not support update with aggregation pipeline, because it is starting from moongodb 4.2 version,

Comment: Oh dear, any idea on how this could be achieved then?

Comment: it is not possible with single query, you need to do 2 queries first query for find and second for update.

Comment: I created a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66348675/how-to-rename-a-field-inside-an-array-with-database-commands-of-azure-cosmos-db

Comment: Is it possible with these limitations?

Comment: I don't think it is possible in single query, you have to do do 2 queries 1) find query 2) do your required changes in client side language 3) update query

Comment: Can you maybe check out the questions I linked above?

Comment: yes i checked it is almost similar to this question, i understand your problem but i can't, i would suggest to ask your question in [mongodb forum](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/) definitely they will provide quick and straight suggestion.