# How to rename a field inside an array with database commands of Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB (3.6 version)?

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I want to change the key of a field from `name` to `title` with [database commands](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/) and NOT the [shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/). Below is a minified version of my collection for reference. I literally only want to change every key called `name` into `title`.

```
[{
  identifier: "x",
  versions: [
    {
      name: "test_name"
      version: "x.x.x"
    },
    {
      name: "test_name"
      version: "x.x.x"
    },
  ]
},
{
  identifier: "y",
  versions: [
    {
      name: "test_name2"
      version: "x.x.x"
    },
    {
      name: "test_name2"
      version: "x.x.x"
    },
  ]
}, ... ]
```

This query basically does exactly what I need, but it, unfortunately, isn't supported by the newest CosmosDB MongoDB-API:

```
db.runCommand({
    update: 'apps',
    updates: [
        {
            q: { "versions.name": { $exists: true } },
            u: [
              {
                $set: {
                    versions: {
                        $map: {
                            input: "$versions",
                            in: {
                                $mergeObjects: [
                                    "$$this",
                                    { "title": "$$this.name" }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
              },
              { $unset: "versions.name" }
            ],
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
```

You can find what is supported here: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36. How could this be achieved with these limitations in mind?

Comment: When run 'db.runCommand()' in mongo shell in cosmosdb mongoapi, I got the error of 'db.runCommand is not implemented on this tool, please use your favorite Mongo framework or third party tools', so I think it can't be achieved upon your requirement of use database commands not the shell''. Maybe any other details or ideas?

Comment: @Tiny-wa I'm using a Jetbrains IDE to execute these commands but you can also use any other database tool like [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-robomongo